# I want to match columns in two different excel files using python

Tags: python

I have two Excel files, say, df1.xlsx and df2.xlsx.

```
data1.xlsx

    Col1

    Aditya1

    Adi

    Aditya_sh

data2.xlsx

    Col1

    Sunil

    Abhishek

    Aditya1
```

I want to match element of data1.Col1 with each row of data2.col1.
if it matches,then write data1.col1 data to another file.
The above data is just an example, so in actual case i have 45k Names in data1 and 35k names in data2

I have tried the below code:

```
data1= pd.read_excel('data1.xlsx')
data2= pd.read_excel('data2.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('output2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

d1=data1['LEI'].values
d2=data2['LEI'].values

for i in range(len(d1)):
       if d1[i] ==d2[i]:
        data1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    elif
        data1.to_excel(writer1, sheet_name='Sheet1')


Output 

Col1
Aditya1
```

Comment: I downvoted this question because of weak specs, no attempt, and no [MCVE]. Please improve the question such that I can upvote you. :)

Comment: @timgeb- I apologies, this is my first post, was not aware of the formatting. I have added my code.could you please help now. Thanks

Comment: Your post still lacks an explanation of what's wrong with your code and the desired output dataframe.

Comment: @timgeb - Modified the question again, pardon please

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking for help with. From a quick look at the code you've posted, you're iterating over the number of items in `d1` but you don't check that `i` is a valid index for `d2`; this may cause some issues, but until you clearly state what the issue is, it's hard for anyone to know how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a match between two columns? If yes, then try below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Aditya1','Adi','Aditya_sh']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Sunil','Abhishek','Aditya1']})
df1.merge(df2,on='col1')
```

Output-

```
col1
0   Aditya1
```

Comment: Yes, but what if I have more than 45k records in data1 file and 35k records in data2 file?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Can you please accept my answer if it satisfies your answer.

Comment: what if i want to add one more column say col3, and want to map all the results which are common between two DF as True, else false?